# Galleria - Fatal Error - No Theme Found IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, galleria, fatal-error

I have built a site using Galleria that works beautifully until it meets IE8

http://milroyandmcaleer.com/Architecture/index.html

Then occasionally throws the no theme found error.  I have scoured the web trying different solutions.  No better.  The link above is where it all began.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the latest version of the program
2. Read this: http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/references/optimize/ (especially point 4)